# What is the rule for making functions private in Python modules?

Tags: python, clean-code, modules

I was wondering what's the principle behind it, and whether I should treat all functions from module that are not used anywhere else at the time as private, and mark them with underscore prefix so others know that these are not used anywhere else. Or maybe only mark as private those that are 'not meant' to be used anywhere else?

For example I have a situation now, where I created a module that basically has one click function that is used from outside, and the logic was encapsulated to many smaller functions that are currently only used by this main function. But some of those smaller functions are likely to be used in the future by others module as well I think. I wonder what to do in such case. Do I make underscore prefix for each function that is currently not being used anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard rule on what should be marked as private.

As a general guideline, you should at least mark everything that is not meant to be used from outside the module (or class) as private, but you can extend that, at your discretion and based on conventions within your team, up to everything that is currently not used outside the module/class.

Marking functions that might be useful for use from other modules as private has both benefits and drawbacks. The benefit is that you don't have to worry about breaking an API when you change the signature of the function. The drawback is that if another module needs the same functionality, either they will duplicate the function, or you need to do some rework to make the function public.